# Java EE Event not observed in JAR module inside EAR/lib

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, glassfish, cdi

**Environment:** Glassfish 3.1.2.2, JSF2, Weld 1.1.4.Final

I have the following structure inside my EAR file:

```
|-- lib
|   `-- client-dummy-jar.jar
|       |-- JarModuleBean.java
|       `-- META-INF
|          |-- MANIFEST.MF
|          `-- beans.xml
|-- META-INF
|   |-- MANIFEST.MF
|   `-- application.xml
|-- client-dummy-ejb.jar
|   |-- ClientEvent.java
|   |-- Application.java
|   |-- EjbModuleBean.java
|   |-- META-INF
|   |   |-- MANIFEST.MF
|   |   `-- beans.xml
`-- client-dummy-web.war
    |-- WEB-INF
    |   |-- web.xml
    |   `-- beans.xml
    `-- index.xhtml
```

Both ejb and the web module have a dependecy to the jar module inside EAR/lib.

**Application.java**

```
@ApplicationScoped
@Named(value = Application.BEAN_NAME)
public class Application implements Serializable {
    public static final String BEAN_NAME = "Application";
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2191033605110202697L;
    @Inject
    private Event<ClientEvent> clientEvent;

    public void fireEvent() {
        clientEvent.fire(new ClientEvent());
    }
}
```

**JarModuleBean.java / EjbModuleBean.java (Everything but the class name/constant is the same**

```
@ApplicationScoped
@Named(value = JarModuleBean.BEAN_NAME)
public class JarModuleBean implements Serializable {
    public static final String BEAN_NAME = "JarModuleBean";
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1583065083930316521L;
    private boolean eventFired = false;

    public String getEventString() {
        if (eventFired) {
            eventFired = false;
            return "Event has been observed in " + BEAN_NAME;
        } else {
            return "No event has been observed in " + BEAN_NAME;
        }
    }

    public void onClientEvent(@Observes ClientEvent event) {
        eventFired = true;
    }
}
```

**index.xhtml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

<h:head>
    <title>Client Dummy</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        Event in JarModule: #{JarModuleBean.eventString}<br />
        Event in EjbModule: #{EjbModuleBean.eventString}<br /><br />

        <h:commandLink id="fireEvent" action="#{Application.fireEvent}">
            <h:outputText value="Fire Event!"/>
        </h:commandLink>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

**Output of index page:**

```
Event in JarModule: 
Event in EjbModule: No event has been observed in EjbModuleBean

Fire Event!
```

**Output after firing the event:**

```
Event in JarModule: 
Event in EjbModule: Event has been observed in EjbModuleBean

Fire Event!
```

In my `application.xml` all three modules (ejb module, web module and java module) are registered.

Event string is returned correctly from EjbModuleBean. So it seems that CDI does not even scan the libraries in the EAR/lib directory on Glassfish 3.1.2.2. According to the Java EE 6 spec (chapter EE.8.2.1) the libraries in the EAR/lib folder (or whatever is specified in the application.xml as `library-directory`) should be visible to every module in the EAR file.

What am I missing?

*Sidenote:* Everything seems to work under 7.1.1Final, but I'm not sure which application server is correct (according to the spec) or if I'm still doing something wrong.

Comment: Sounds like a glassfish bug.

Comment: Actually, what happens if you try injecting the JarModule bean into the EjbModule?

Comment: @JohnAment This would result in cyclic dependencies? - Or what do you mean exactly?